# Parse livescores from web site

Tags: php, screen-scraping

I was thinking of parsing live scores from a web site via PHP and them use them for an application I am planning to implement, so my question is is it legal to do that, parse info from web site and use it ? If I quote the source if the info ?

Comment: Regardless of legal issues, it's always polite to ask first... unless, of course, their site says that the data may be freely used without asking.

Comment: I would still ask in that situation anyways just to be polite as you said. :) Also Venno's users as they load his web site the scores will be updated thus increasing the source site's traffic unless its something that he automatically does once a day or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is only legal if you do it according to their terms and conditions.

Usually its asking them first and then giving credit to where it is due.

Comment: To add: Major League Baseball sued companies who were merely watching games on TV and transmitting live scores to cell phones as a service. They argued that live updates can be viewed as a rebroadcast of their games! If it's a major sporting league that you intend to do this with, I'd suggest you lawyer up ahead of time.